# unable to print json value with alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, flickr, swifty-json

I am trying to get data with flickr API and I wrote a simple code with Alamofire and swiftyJSON to get this data from flickr but I am able to print the data size but when I try to print the json, my `catch` block runs. my codes are shown below

```
func getPhotos(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {

        let parameter: [String: Any] = [
            "method": PHOTOS_METHOD,
            "api_key": FLICKR_API_KEY,
            "per_page": PER_PAGE,
            "page": PAGE,
            "format": FORMAT_TYPE,
            "nojsoncallback": JSON_CALLBACK]

        Alamofire.request(FLICKR_URL, method: .get, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HEADER).responseString { (response) in

            if response.result.error == nil {

                guard let data = response.data else {return}

                do {
                    if let json = try JSON(data: data).array {
                        print(json)
                    }
                    completion(true)
                } catch {
                    print("eroorrrre")
                    completion(false)
                }

                print("CALL CORRECT")
                print(data)

                completion(true)
            }
            else {
                completion(false)
                debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
            }
        }
    }
```

my console log

```
eroorrrre
CALL CORRECT
128 bytes
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, any help would be appriciated

Comment: **Never ever** print  a meaningless literal string like `eroorrrre` in a catch clause, print the `error` instance. Most likely it shows you *what* you are *doing wrong here*. And in case of an error you are calling `completion` twice. Don't do that.

Comment: noted thanks I would correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
Alamofire.request(FLICKR_URL, method: .get, parameters: parameter, headers: HEADER).responseJSON { response in // call responseJSON instead of responseString

    if response.result.isSuccess { // If http request is success

        let json: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!) // JSON format from SwiftyJSON (I suppose you are using it)

        guard let data = json.array else { // You suppose that json is array of objects
            print("Unexpected JSON format")
            completion(false)
        }

        print(data) 
        completion(true)

    } else {
        print(response.error)
        completion(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine but any reason why my code was not working? I have always used that and it always works

Comment: @King in your case response.data wasn't in correct format for JSON

Comment: hi kindly help check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360597/pagination-with-collectionview-working-with-api