# UICollectionViewCell does not have a reuseIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application where I display images in a `UICollectionView`, the problem I am getting now is whenever I click the button that takes me to the view controller with the `UICollectionView`, the app crashes with the message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the cell returned from
>   -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling
>   -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:'

I have the cell intact so I do not know why it is crashing

```
extension SavedPhotoVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SAVED_CELL, for: indexPath) as? SavedCell {

            let flickerPhoto = itemArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.configueCell(flickerPhotoModel: flickerPhoto, index: indexPath.item)
            return cell
        }
        return SavedCell()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemArray.count
    }
```

Further code can be added on request.

Comment: Did you register the `SavedCell` using `SAVED_CELL` ?

Comment: Yes. I did that in my storyboard

Comment: Could you please set a breakpoint and check which return is actually executed ? `return cell` or `return SavedCell()` .

Comment: return cell is not called. app crashes and shows same error

Comment: Could you please show us how you register your cell in the storyboard and how the value of `SAVED_CELL` is set ?

Comment: Another thing, don't forget to set the custom class of your sublcassed `SavedCell`.

Comment: Thanks @RatulSharker

Comment: you could help checkout this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360597/pagination-with-uicollectionview-working-with-api

Comment: What was the issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here

```
return SavedCell()
```

You shouldn't return an empty cell , that the collection will dequeue it later and find it without an identifier , the straight forward way to do this is

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SAVED_CELL, for: indexPath) as! SavedCell 

    let flickerPhoto = itemArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.configueCell(flickerPhotoModel: flickerPhoto, index: indexPath.item)

    return cell

 }
```

Comment: I am using collectionview

Comment: @Sh_Khan kindly help with this question please. Been working on it three straight days https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369529/uicollectionview-not-paginating-vertically